# Implementing implication logical operator in scala

Tags: scala, operators

I was wondering if there is any possibility to implement a logical implication in scala.
For example:

```
a implies b
```

translating into:

```
!a || b
```

where `a` and `b` are some expressions that evaluate to `Boolean`.

I initially started with following, but that is a wrong approach

```
  implicit def extendedBoolean(a : Boolean) = new {
    def implies(b : Boolean) = {
      !a || b
    }
  }
```

since it will evaluate both `a` and `b` regardless the value of `a`. The correct solution would only evaluate `b` when `a` is true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use a call-by-name parameter, I believe the following should suffice:

```
implicit def extendedBoolean(a : Boolean) = new {
    def implies(b : => Boolean) = {
      !a || b
    }
  }
```

Explanation:

You must pass some value in for `b` but you do not want that expression evaluated; Scala can automatically convert the expression into a function that takes no arguments and evaluates to the expression.  Your `implies` operator then evaluates that nullary (zero-argument) function if need be.

The compiler knows that it can do this conversion because of the type signature you have provided, `=> Boolean`.  This [post](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/138) explains in better detail, but its title alone is a very good nutshell explanation of what is going on: ["Automatic Type-Dependent Closure Construction"](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/138).

This feature of Scala enables one to write control constructs, perhaps as easily as one might write them using macros in other languages.  Observe how easily they reimplement a while loop using two call-by-name parameters: one for the conditional and one for the body.

```
object TargetTest2 extends Application {
  //type signature not too terribly mysterious
  def whileLoop(cond: => Boolean)(body: => Unit): Unit =
    if (cond) {
      body
      whileLoop(cond)(body)
    }

  //about as easy to use as a plain-old while() loop
  var i = 10
  whileLoop (i > 0) {
    println(i)
    i -= 1
  }
}
```

Comment: What you call *nullary function* is called *call-by-name argument* in Scala.

Comment: True. As the page on the Scala website that I linked to explains, "so-called _call-by-name_ evaluation" is implemented in Scala by automatic conversion of an expression to a nullary function.  I think it is more interesting and more educational to describe _how_ Scala implements the language feature than to just note how one makes use of call-by-name.

Answer (score 4):

You want to make `b` a function that must be evaluated.  That way it will only be evaluated if it is actually accessed.

You do this by changing its type to `=> Boolean`, meaning something that evaluates to a `Boolean` without needing any input.

```
implicit def extendedBoolean(a: Boolean) = new {
  def implies(b: => Boolean) = {
    !a || b
  }
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
scala> true implies { println("evaluated"); true }
evaluated
res0: Boolean = true

scala> false implies { println("evaluated"); true }
res1: Boolean = true
```

Notice that when `a` is `true`, `b` is evaluated (printing "evaluated"). But when `a` is `false`, it is not evaluated (nothing printed).